# Writing a jquery handler more efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#element").on("change", function(){
    calculateValue();
});

function calculateValue(){
    $("#result").html($("#int1").val() + $("#int2").val()); 
}
calculateValue();
```

In the above (example) code, I am calculating the results of an element every time an element is changed.

However I also want to do this calculation before the user has changed any values. So in the above example I just call the function.

It seems messy that I am calling the function in two places. When I have a few of these, it starts looking very messy. Is there any better way to write this?

Comment: You can bind and trigger like `$("#element").on("change", calculateValue).trigger('change');`. However I personally follow your current approach.

Comment: @Satpal, don't you think this is just another syntax to call the function, but its the same as calling the same function two times as Bazlid has done ?

Comment: It's not messy. If you want the function to be called, the first time, I would go with your current approach.

Comment: I'd use @Satpal's way of passing the function though. So the first bind looks like this `$("#element").on("change", calculateValue);`.

Comment: @Ivar using `$("#element").on("change", function() {calculateValue()})` would also have its advantages, because the function `calculateValue` would receive the same parameters in both cases (in the given one, it would be no parameter). Using `$("#element").on("change", calculateValue)` would pass an event for `change` and nothing if it is called directly. Which one to perferre is for sure opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare two events to the elements as below:

```
$("#element").ready(function(){calculateValue();})
.bind("change", function() {
    calculateValue();
});
```

**FROM THE API:**

The `.ready()` method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate.

Comment: Mind you, this way of using ready event is deprecated  as per the api docs @ http://api.jquery.com/ready/